# How do I test an IronWorker task locally using the CLI?

Tags: ironworker

How do I test an IronWorker task locally using the CLI?

Answer (score 4):

```
iron_worker run worker_name -p '{"foo":"bar","baz":[1,2,3]}'
```

where optional "-p" flag - payload

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Docker installed you can also run your worker locally using a Docker command:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)":/worker -w /worker iron/php sh -c 'php name_of_worker.php'
```

Just make sure your Docker Quickstart Terminal is up and running.

If it works on Docker then it will work on IronIO. As stated in the Iron docs [here](http://dev.iron.io/worker/getting_started/).